# When I use json_encode() on the object with private properties, it returns empty object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In theory, when using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` type it should return an object of the specified class and assign values from table columns to properties of a class, even if they are private. If there is no property in class and no `__set()`  functions specified it should create a new public property.

This is my class:

```
class Product
{
    private string $id;
    private string $name;
    private int $price;

    public function __set(string $name, $value): void
    {
    }

    public function __get(string $name) : void
    {
    }
    
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And this is my method to fetch all records from the table:

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";

        $statement = $this->conn->query($sql);
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Product');
    }
```

This is returning an array of empty Product objects, even tho this should assign values to existing properties if the name is the same. It's working when properties are public, but not when they are private or protected.

I know that assigning to private properties is kinda weird behavior, but it is well documented on the internet including php.net, is there a possibility that this feature was removed recently? I can't find any info about it in the changelogs or on the stack.

If this behavior is deprecated now, please would you kindly advise me how can I fetch info from one table into different objects classes without explicitly using setters of the class?

Thank you for help in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers, I have determined that indeed PDO is working as it should and when I var_dump the array it looks fine:

```
    /home/wwwroot/app/src/ProductController.php:67:
array (size=9)
  0 => 
    object(Product)[7]
      private string 'id' => *uninitialized*
      private string 'name' => string 'Harry Potter' (length=12)
      private int 'price' => int 200
  1 => 
    object(Product)[8]
      private string 'id' => *uninitialized*
      private string 'name' => string 'War and Peace' (length=13)
      private int 'price' => int 2000
```

However, when I use json_encode() on the array it's just showing empty object's, so I presume it's because I need to give assoc array to that function instead of array of objects?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the results you get.

Comment: Can't confirm. PHP PDO FETCH_CLASS definitely [DOES assign to private class properties](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/3fe3f0ecec173db1831b4af2dfde296f/)

Comment: I think you should turn to your book where it explains what does "private" mean...

Answer (score -2):

The issue may be due to your empty `__set()` and `__get()` methods, which override the default behavior of `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. Remove or comment out these magic methods to allow PDO to populate private properties.

```php
class Product
{
    private string $id;
    private string $name;
    private int $price;

    // Remove or comment out these magic methods
    // public function __set(string $name, $value): void
    // {
    // }

    // public function __get(string $name) : void
    // {
    // }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

If you've specifically added empty `__set()` and `__get()` methods to prevent dynamic property creation, the `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` will not be able to populate private or protected properties. Consider using `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` flag to make sure that the constructor is called before properties are assigned.

```php
public function getAll()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
    $statement = $this->conn->query($sql);
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Product');
}
```

Also, check out this awesome source of PHP PDO information. Really nice read.

[(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) from **phpdelusions.net**

Comment: May be? Why not to test it?

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer and link to the tutorial, unfortunately that's not it, I've left those methods empty to block the addition of any other public properties from the table to the object.